# Can chrome or other browsers be customized to run a local JavaScript file on all tabs open?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, browser, configuration, default

Please how can i attach a JavaScript file to my chrome, so as any page loads it runs the code on that page?

Does chrome save the html pages it loads somewhere on local disk c that it can be accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### solution 1:

As a previous user said, you can build your own extension and you can run it in chrome.

#### solution 2:

IF it is only a temporary task, you can click on **F12** (open the DevTools) and click on **Console**. There you can paste your own javascript function / script that will be run in the current page.

*Note* this works only for the current page (where you have the console opened).

#### solution 3:

You might want to try and use Selenium
https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/selenium-ide/mooikfkahbdckldjjndioackbalphokd?hl=en

Answer (score 2):

You can make a chrome extension to run your script.